# pandas: Utilizar la primera fila como índices quitando siguientes

Tags: python, pandas, indices

No consigo encontrar la opción en [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) para utilizar la primera línea del archivo de texto como indices pero además ignorar alguna línea siguiente.

Por ejemplo, utilizando datos de la [Junta de Andalucía](http://www.juntadeandalucia.es/agriculturaypesca/ifapa/ria/servlet/FrontController?action=Static&url=coordenadas.jsp&c_provincia=4&c_estacion=4) ([descargar datos ejemplo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CAChemE/curso-python-datos/master/data/tabernas_meteo_data.txt)):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que funciona pero me obliga a introducir los nombres a mano es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("../data/tabernas_meteo_data.txt",
            skiprows=2,  # salta las dos primeras líneas
            delim_whitespace=True, 
            names = ['fecha','Tmax','Tmin','Tmedia','precipitacion'], # nombres de índice manuales
            parse_dates=["fecha"], dayfirst=True,
            usecols=[0,2,3,4,5], index_col=['fecha']).head(5)
```

¿Existe alguna opción importar directamente los nombres del cabecero y saltar la segunda línea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplemente pasale una **lista con los índices de cada línea a no tener en cuenta** al parámetro `skiprows`. Recuerda que se empieza por el indice 0, que corresponde al header en este caso. Dejo un ejemplo fácilmente reproducible:

**datos.txt:**

> Nombre,Edad
>   Luís,24
>   Laura,19
>   Jesús,28
>   Carmen,34

**Código:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("datos.txt", skiprows=[1]) # En este caso eliminamos la fila 1
print(df)
```

**Salida:**

> ```
>    Nombre   Edad
> 0   Laura     19
> 1   Jesus     28
> 2  Carmen     34
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Dejo aquí el ejemplo resuelto para los asistentes.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("../data/tabernas_meteo_data.txt",
            skiprows=[1],  # salta la segunda fila
            delim_whitespace=True, 
            parse_dates=["FECHA"], dayfirst=True,
            usecols=[0,2,3,4,5], index_col=['FECHA']).head(5)
```

:)